# Opening Outlook through VBA crashes for unknown reason

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code to open a list of email-adresses directly in outlook. The email list consists of roughly 100 email-adresses.

If I let the code run for only parts of the list it works just fine for all different parts, but as soon as I let it run for the whole list I get a runtime error '5. Does anyone have a suggestion what causes this problem? I would be very thankful.

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Range("I10").Value = "Wahr" Then

Dim strAddress As String
Dim lastCell As Long
Dim i As Integer

Worksheets("Output").Activate

lastCell = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 13 To lastCell
   If strAddress = "" Then
   strAddress = Cells(i, 2).Value
Else
  strAddress = strAddress & ";" & Cells(i, 2).Value
End If
Next i

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="mailto:" & strAddress 'this line gives me the error
End If
```

[image]

EDIT: The weird thing is, that it doesnt really matter which "groups" I choose. It seems to be a question of how many adresses I pick.

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of your `Output` worksheet?

Comment: @Zac, I added it. Normally the e-mail adresses would be from B13 downwards depending on which groups you marked. I deleted them here for safety reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by *I am using this code to open a list of email-adresses directly in outlook.*

The code appears to create a single blank email with each cell in B13 downwards providing the email addresses?

Maybe this code below will help.
It uses late binding (so no references needed) to get a reference to Outlook, it then creates an email and adds the email addresses to it as recipients before finally displaying it.  You can change the `.Display` to `.Send` to send the email rather than just display it.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim oOL As Object
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim rAddRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    Set oOL = CreateOL

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
        Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)
        Set rAddRange = .Range("B13", rLastCell)
    End With

    Set oMail = oOL.CreateItem(0)

    With oMail
        For Each rCell In rAddRange
            .Recipients.Add rCell.Value
        Next rCell
        .Display
    End With

End Sub

Public Function CreateOL() As Object

    Dim oTmpOL As Object

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Creating an instance of Outlook is different from Excel. '
    'There can only be a single instance of Outlook running,  '
    'so CreateObject will GetObject if it already exists.     '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set oTmpOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set CreateOL = oTmpOL

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateOL."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: You are right, I formulated my question pretty poorly. But your code does exactly what I tried to achieve. Thank you very very much for your kind and quick help!